# NullPointerException when using an hexadecimal value as the parameter of a method

Tags: java, exception, javafx, colors, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a simple program that consists of a window with 8 buttons with different colors added to a `VBox` that then is added to the program stage's scene.

For changing a button's color, I have to call the `setRippleColor()` method, whose definition is the following:

```
public void setRippleColor(Color color) {
        ((Shape) ((SkinBase) getSkin()).getChildren().get(0)).setFill(color);
    }
```

The problem is that when I call this method using a `Color` object as its parameter, I get a `NullPointerException`.

For example, if I use this code:

```
        buttonGreen.setRippleColor((Color.web("0x259B24")));
        buttonOrange.setRippleColor(Color.web("0xe67e22"));
        buttonBlue.setRippleColor(Color.web("0x3498db"));
        buttonPurple.setRippleColor(Color.web("0x9b59b6"));
        buttonYellow.setRippleColor(Color.web("0xf1c40f"));
        buttonRed.setRippleColor(Color.web("0xe74c3c"));
        buttonBrown.setRippleColor(Color.web("0x663300"));
        buttonGrey.setRippleColor(Color.web("0x222222"));

        VBox verticalLayout = new VBox(8);
        verticalLayout.getChildren().addAll(buttonGreen,
                                            buttonOrange,
                                            buttonBlue,
                                            buttonPurple,
                                            buttonYellow,
                                            buttonRed,
                                            buttonBrown,
                                            buttonGrey);
```

the console is going to say this:

```
 Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at CustomButton.setRippleColor(CustomButton.java:166)
    at StartingPoint.start(StartingPoint.java:25)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
```

Being the 166th and 25th lines of code the definition of the method and the first call thereof, respectively.

Nevertheless, if instead of using an hexadecimal value as a color I use one of the default colors of the `Color` class (`Color.GREEN`, for example), everything runs perfectly.

It's important to mention that I'm not using the `java.awt.Color` class instead of `javafx.scene.paint.Color`; the library is no the problem.

**UPDATE:** I did some rudamentary logging in order to know what's `null`.

Instead of using `Color.web("...")` as a parameter for `setRippleColor()`, I created a few `Color` objects whose definition is what at the beggining was the `setRippleColor()`'s parameter, and I surrounded the calls to the `setRippleMethod()` with the following `try{} catch{}`:

```
Color green = Color.web("0x259B24");

        try {
            buttonGreen.setRippleColor(green);
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {

            SkinBase skin = (SkinBase) buttonGreen.getSkin();
            ObservableList<Node> children = skin.getChildren();
            Shape shape = (Shape) skin.getChildren().get(0);

            System.out.println("Color " + green);
            System.out.println("Skin: " + skin);
            System.out.println("Children: " + children);
            System.out.println("Shape: " + shape);

        }
```

And this is what the console prints out:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StartingPoint.start(StartingPoint.java:31)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
```

For as far as I understand, this means that the button's skin's children return `null`, but I don't understand why does this not happen when I use `Color.GREEN` instead of the `Color` object found in the above code.

**UPDATE 2**: It turns out that when I use `Color.GREEN` as a parameter for `setRippleColor()` the result is the same that if I use `Color.web("#colorstring")`, thing that is obvious and there wouldn't be an explanation if that wasn't the case. I don't know why, but I have the memory of using `Color.GREEN` and having the program running without any errors.

The good thing is that now I will remember that every time that something doesn't make sense, I have to run the code again and make sure that it doesn't make sense to me because I don't have enough knowledge about the topic, and not because it never happened.

So, the problem was due to that the button's skin hasn't been initialized before the `setRippleColor()` method is called.

This is how I solved it:

```
try{
((Shape) ((SkinBase) getSkin()).getChildren().get(0)).setFill(color);
} catch (NullPointerException exception){
    createDefaultSkin();
    setRippleColor(color);
}
```

If the skin hasn't been initialized when the method is called, it's initialized and then the `setRippleColor()` calls himself again.

Comment: Do some logging to see what's null. It is either the skin, the skin's child list (unlikely), or the first child of the skin (pretty unlikely). Perhaps you are somehow calling this before the skin is initialized?

Comment: Even if you do manage to get it to work, this is a pretty fragile design.  The skin implementations for things like Buttons in JavaFX 8 are not part of the public API and could (and likely will) change in a binary incompatible way for later Java versions.  So I think you should rethink what you are trying to do and the means in which you try to accomplish it.  I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but normally you can use CSS to set colors on buttons (e.g. `button.setStyle("-fx-base: palegreen;");`)

Comment: I guess, in light of your comment that `Color.GREEN` works, also check that `Color.web(...)` is not returning null, though I find it hard to believe it would.

Comment: Nevertheless, does any exact reason exist to do not use CSS to simply color your `Button`s?

Comment: @James_D Sorry for answering late, I didn't know what logging is and I wasn't going to talk without knowing what I'm talking about.  If the null value were coming from the skin, the program would still throw an exception when I use `Color.GREEN` as a parameter. The `null` is for sure coming from the `Color.web(...)` parameter, but I have no idea about why does this happen.

Comment: @jewelsea I changed my code by implementing your solution and everything runs without any problems, but the good thing about changing the button's color by using a method is that I don't override the whole CSS file. I think that it is possible to find the line in which the `-fx-background-color: ;` is though, so maybe I could override the `setRippleColor()` method in a way that it could override just that specific line of code. I'll try that and I'll tell you what was the result.

Comment: @JavaNoob By "logging" I really just meant something as crude as putting things in variables and printing them to the console: i.e. `System.out.println("Color: "+color);` `SkinBase skin = (SkinBase) getSkin();` `System.out.println("Skin: "+skin);`, `ObservableList<Node> children = skin.getChildren();` `System.out.println("Child nodes: "+children);` `Shape circle = (Shape) children.get(0);` `System.out.println("Circle: "+circle);` `circle.setFill(color);`. So you are presumably saying that you see `Color: null` if you try this.

Comment: @James_D I solved the problem. You should post your comments as an answer so then I can accept it.

Comment: It's pretty bad form to use `try {...} catch { ... }` for implementing your logic. (You should write code that strives to avoid exceptions being thrown, where possible.) See my answer for a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you are trying to call these methods before the skin has been initialized. In this scenario, `getSkin()` will return `null` and thus `((SkinBase)getSkin()).getChildren()` will throw a null pointer exception.

A simple way to avoid this is to do a null check:

```
public void setRippleColor(Color color) {
    if (getSkin() == null) {
        createDefaultSkin();
    }
    SkinBase skin = (SkinBase) getSkin();
    Shape shape = (Shape) skin.getChildren().get(0);
    shape.setFill(color);
}
```

You can probably vastly improve on this code: it seems you should really know somewhere in the code what the first child of the skin is, and should be able to reference it directly. This will at least provide a fix, though.